# Use OpenVPN to manage certain ports on server

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I have an Ubuntu server set up with OpenVPN, Minecraft, and TeamSpeak3 among other applications.

I am able to SSH into it, use Samba for my NAS, and even have each of my computers using TS3 and Minecraft together successfully; all on the LAN. My goal is to allow the Minecraft and TS3 ports to be accessible outside my LAN.

I have my ISP modem forwarding the ports to my subnet's router and that router forwarding to the server. Great. Minecraft and TS3 works and is accessible **within** the LAN regardless if the VPN is UP or DOWN.

I'd like to leave the VPN up, but exclude the Minecraft and TS3 from the VPNs route.

How do I configure the routes?

**UPDATE**

I'd like for the outside clients (unknown OS) to connect to the MC & TS servers that are being hosted on an inside Ubuntu Server 16.04.

The Ubuntu Server is hosting MC, TS, Samba services, Plex, uTorrent and SickRage. OpenVPN is running on here as well.

My ISP router is unmodified and my subnet router is an unmodified ASUS. I did open and forward the appropriate ports, daisy-chained, to the Ubuntu Server.

My internal clients consist of a mix of OS X, Windows 10, and various Android versions. Each of the internal clients are able to access the Ubuntu services listed above using the server's internally assigned IP.

In addition, the iptables on the Ubuntu Server are completely open, which once I figure out how to get the MC & TS working, I can add additional restrictions.

```
sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

**UPDATE 2**
I just went through my routers and verified the port forwarding and firewall exceptions. Everythings square. At the CLI, I ran `sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn stop` and visited http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/.

The returned results: `Port 10011 is open on 97.*.*.*`

`sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn start` resulted in: `Port 10011 is closed on 97.*.*.*`

*ifconfig -a*

```
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 50:e5...
          inet addr:192.168.1.89  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::52e5:49ff:fedd:d345/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:29183 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5791 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:1
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:5338487 (5.3 MB)  TX bytes:770420 (770.4 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3772 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3772 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:679389 (679.3 KB)  TX bytes:679389 (679.3 KB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:10.*.*.*  P-t-P:10.*.*.*  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:371 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:647 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:101055 (101.0 KB)  TX bytes:83561 (83.5 KB)
```

*oVPN config*

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote vpnprovider.com 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
tls-client
remote-cert-tls server
auth-user-pass login.conf
comp-lzo
verb 1
reneg-sec 0
crl-verify crl.pem
```

Comment: You ask about about OpenVPN, but you mention it only briefly. Is the connection outgoing? Does your server terminate VPN? Does your router terminate VPN? Now it's unclear what you have and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Also unclear to me. From what I understood, you want to achieve incoming openVPN, incoming TS3, incoming Minecraft. From my point of view this should already work, because every server runs on its own port.

Comment: @techraf Im not too familiar with what you're talking about; Im pretty new to private VPNs. I followed the instructions on https://raspinotes.wordpress.com/2013/06/04/setup-vpn-with-privateinternetaccess-com/ and am being piped through their server.

Comment: @stueja each do work and each are running on their own port. Each work from within the LAN, but not outside the LAN, unless I stop the VPN service

Comment: OK... could you update your question with the details techraf asked? a) from which computer (inside/outside of LAN, which operating system) do you want to connect to which computer (inside/outside of LAN, which OS) with which application (TS, MC, oVPN)? b) where does openVPN run, on the Ubuntu server or on another device, if so, which one?

Comment: I've added an update.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your update, here a couple things to check:

#### Routes

you were asking how to configure the routes.

From the information given above, the Ubuntu server needs to know a route to the internet via the subnet router's inside interface, and the subnet router needs to know a route to the internet via the ISP router's inside interface (if it acts as a router). Also, the ISP router needs to know the route to your internal LAN via the subnet router's outside interface.

However, I assume that routing is OK, because you are already able to use OpenVPN into your Ubuntu server.

#### Ports

All necessary ports must be allowed through any firewalls, i. e. on the Ubuntu server, the subnet router and the ISP router.
Those are

```
Port 25565 TCP and UDP for Minecraft
Port 9987 UDP, 10011 TCP and 30033 TCP for TeamSpeak3
just like (usually)
Port 1194 UDP for OpenVPN
```

So, given that your ISP router has the capability and need to forward ports, the ISP router should be set up to forward those ports to the Ubuntu server. Since the ISP router knows the route to the IP of the Ubuntu server, it will send the packets to the subnet router.

Also on the subnet router, the above mentioned ports must be open and forwarded to the Ubuntu server.

## Update

As it turned out, OpenVPN in client mode is being used to connect to a remote VPN server.

### Alternative A

You can advise OpenVPN client to not change your default gateway. This will, depending on the scenario in which you want to use that VPN, render your VPN useless. This alternative will allow you to reach the VPN server and the network behind it. (I use it to manage my PCs at home whilst being able to browse the internet without VPN).

Adding

```
route-nopull
route <vpn.servers.ip.address> 255.255.255.0
```

and optionally, depending on your setup

```
route-metric 50
```

to the config will

- not adhere to the routes pushed by the server
- add a route to the VPN server
- set the route's metric to a low value (aka high priority) so that this route is being used over the default gateway if you want to reach the VPN server.

is the address which appears as your default gateway with the second lowest metric in your default, unchanged OpenVPN client setup, e. g. 10.8.0.1.

#### Additional routes

Unaware of the scenario in which VPN is useful to you, you can, of course add more routes to those hosts or networks which you want to reach via the VPN.

```
route <remote.host.ip.address> vpn_gateway
```

### Alternative 2

Establish policy based routing, in other words, allow everything through the VPN except the ports you are using for TS and MC: see [here: Iptables exception for specific port on Unix&Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/214916).

- configure iptables (following the linked example, be sure to change IP addresses, ports and interface names to your setup)
- change routing to policy routing

Since your iptables policies are set to `ACCEPT`, you do not need those lines from the example:

> ```
> # Always accept loopback traffic
> /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
>
> # Allow established connections, and those not coming from the outside
> /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
> /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
> /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
> ```

Comment: I had alreaxy configured the firewalls on my routers to open up and forward the necessary ports. I was able to get an outside computer to access the MC instance while oVPN was stopped, but not started. Should I add a second IP to the server? Would that help?

Comment: I do not understand how OpenVPN can get in the way here. Is openVPN running in TAP or TUN mode?

Comment: It looks like the config is persisting TUN. See Update 2 for info.

Comment: Uh... it is a vpn CLIENT config which you run on the Ubuntu server to a vpn provider? I was assuming OpenVPN in SERVER mode. Since you tested the same IP address `97.x.x.x` I assume that this is the IP address assigned by your ISP, not by the VPN provider. I assume that users should connect to this IP for TS/MC also. Which, at the moment, does not work because the OpenVPN client will route all traffic to the VPN server. What is the VPN good for in this scenario?

Comment: so then how do I open the ports so others can use TS and MC?

Comment: It depends on the scenario I asked for. I will update my answer.